# jQuery Two buttons making a picture move from left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I want to make a picture (stickman picture) move from left to right as I click one of the two buttons that say "<<" and ">>". 
Here's my code,

```
function personLeft() {
                $('#img').animate({left:'50px'});
            }
function personRight() {
                $('#img').animate({right:'50px'});
            }
```

Here's the buttons,

```
<button id='left' onclick='personRight()'><<</button>
<button id='right' onclick='personLeft()'>>></button>
```

For some reason, this doesn't work. It only makes him travel once to the right, or once to the left. I've tried doing this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#left').click(function(){
        $('#img').animate({left:'50px'});
    });
    $('#right').click(function(){
        $('#img').animate({left:'50px'});
    });
});
```

but it just did the same thing as the functions.
If you need to see what I mean exactly, here's the [link](http://dotcomaftereverything.com/jquery/game).

So, all I want to know is how can it be made that every time I click the right button, it'll go right for 50 pixels and every time I click the left button, it'll go left for 50 pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently just settings its position to 50px, what you want to do is add 50px from its current position:

```
$('#left').click(function(){
    $('#img').animate({
        left:'+=50px'
    });
});
```

Check http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp - Using Relative Values for more information

Comment: Holy crap, thank you so much. For some reason I kind just.. forgot about that. Is there any way I can make it if you click left/right arrow on the keyboards?

Comment: For keyboard, you might want to look into: http://api.jquery.com/keydown/ documentation and examples on that page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to move element to the left.

```
$('#left').click(function(){
    $('#img').animate({left:'-50px'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for moving left, try this

```
$('#img').animate({left:'-50px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying directly `50px` you need to add or subtract that from the previous value.

Try doing something like

```
$('#left').click(function(){
    var left = parseInt($('#img').css('left'));
    $('#img').animate({left:(left - 50) + 'px'});
});
```

And something similar for `#right`